# Push mysql database script to server using git

Tags: mysql, git

I need to take backup of MySQL database script(without data) periodically. And also I want to push the script to server along with source code using git. I already done push and pull the source code using git. But I want to push the DB script too. How to achieve this using git? Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by pushing the DB script with git? A .sql file can be added with git add <file>, committed, and pushed. If you mean synchronizing the DB changes with application changes, then that's a different question.

Comment: yeah the same thing. if I alter any table and push the script to server, the server should take backup of that script? will it work what you said?

Comment: I do not knw the meaning of synchronizing DB. but I want to take backup the DB script as I am doing my source code

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if Git is the best place to store a backup of a DB depending upon how the DB is expected grow. However if the desire is to store the SQL backup in Git, this can be done using mysqldump and git commands if the following is executed from a git repo:

```
mysqldump -h <host> -u <user> -p <db_name> > <sql_file>
git add <sql_file>
git commit -m "Latest mysqldump"
git push
```

For example:

```
mysqldump -h 127.0.0.1 -u mydbuser -p mydbschema > 'db/currentBackup.sql'
git add 'db/currentBackup.sql'
git commit -m "Latest mysqldump"
git push
```

More options are available in the MySQL documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: thanks a lot. But I also have the doubt that git will store the backup of DB scripts automatically after pushing

Comment: Git will store whatever is put in the file.

Comment: yeah that’s okay. but before pushing script along with code, do I need to dump the script ervytime? git wont take the changes automatically?

Comment: The dump gives a sql script that would recreate the database. Git will look at this as a change set from the previous script so would have a diff. If mysqldump generates the sql script consistently, then git should have a decent diff showing the incremental changes from commit to commit.